# Xamarin Forms throw Exception is not found in xmlns clr-namespace:

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work in xamarin forms for cross mobile application but IList variable want show Count then throw Exception.

**Exception Detail:**
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 19:64. Type  PersonFactory not found in xmlns clr-namespace:MHG.Sample.Model;assembly=MHG.Sample

**.Xaml File Content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MHG.Sample.Model;assembly=MHG.Sample"
             x:Class="MHG.Sample.Templates.ListViewSampleWithLocalImage">

  <ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform  x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,20,0,0" />
  </ContentPage.Padding>

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:ImageSourceConverter x:Key="ImageSourceConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ListView x:Name="LstPeople" ItemsSource="{ Binding . }" Footer="{ Binding Count, Source={ x:Static local: PersonFactory.People }">

        <ListView.Header>
          <ContentView Padding="0,5" BackgroundColor="#fff">
            <Label FontSize="Medium" TextColor="#000" Text="MHG Sample" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
          </ContentView>
        </ListView.Header>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ImageCell Text="{ Binding Fullname }" TextColor="Black" Detail="{ Binding Description }" DetailColor="Gray" ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={ StaticResource ImageSourceConverter }"></ImageCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.FooterTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView Padding="0,5,5,0">
              <Label FontSize="Medium"
                     TextColor="#666"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                     Text="{Binding ., StringFormat = '{0} kişi mevcut.' }"></Label>
            </ContentView>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.FooterTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

**PersonFactory.cs File Content(this file is .xaml Data Factory)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MHG.Sample.Model
{
    public static class PersonFactory
    {
        public static List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

        static PersonFactory()
        {
            var list =  new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            for (var i = 0; i < new Random().Next(10, 100); i++)
            {
                var person = new Person(i, Faker.Name.First(), Faker.Name.Last(), $"{new Random().Next(1, 10)}.jpg")
                {
                    Description = Faker.Lorem.Sentence()
                };
                list.Add(person);
            }
            People.AddRange(list);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit(2016/12/06 12:23AM GMT +3)**

Solved this problem;
`x:Static local: PersonFactory.People` 
remove blank space local: between PersonFactory keyword.
`x:Static local:PersonFactory.People`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has having error in  line 19

```
<ListView x:Name="LstPeople" ItemsSource="{ Binding . }" Footer="{ Binding Count, Source={ x:Static local: PersonFactory.People }">
```

...Please check that

Answer (score 2):

Verify in your project settings that the "Assembly name" is set to MHG.Sample.

In Visual Studio: Right click on the shared (Portable) project and click on "Properties". On the "Library" tab there should be a box with label "Assembly Name".

OR

In Xamarin Studio: Right click on the shared project (not the iOS or Android projects) and click options. On the "Output" screen there should be a box with label "Assembly name".